# ToolBar cannot scroll off the screen thoroughly even if I used NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

I would like the TabLayout to stay in screen and the ToolBar to be off screen when scrolling, but the ToolBar has always got some part staying in the screen. I searched some codes on the Internet and run them but they have the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ihandy.a2014011385.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/channels_tabs">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ihandy.a2014011385.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and java code

```
TabLayout channels = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.channels_tabs);
channels.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
channels.addTab(channels.newTab().setText("123"));
channels.addTab(channels.newTab().setText("123"));
channels.addTab(channels.newTab().setText("123"));
```

This is the effect now

[image]

Comment: use CollapsingToolBar it will work for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share your values-v21/styles.xml ?
From the looks of it, your Status Bar appears to be transparent. So either set a colour for it, or remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout`.

Alternatively, you can add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your AppBarLayout too.

You can take a look at [this article](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/), which shows how to properly create layouts with CoordinatorLayout. You can compare your styles and XML.

For more on what `fitsSystemWindows` actually does, read this [Medium article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.l1jvup2yv) by Ian Lake.

Comment: Removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout` works for me.